# Complete TFS Pull Request programmatically

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

Using the **Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client (15.112.1)** to connect to a **TFS 2017 Update 2** server we can get details about an existing PR like this:

```
var connection = new VssConnection(collectionUri, credentials);
var client = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
var pr = await client.GetPullRequestByIdAsync(pullRequestId);
```

Also, we can create new PR like this:

```
var pr = await client.CreatePullRequestAsync(
        new GitPullRequest
        {
          SourceRefName = "master",
          TargetRefName = "develop",
          Title = "[Automatic Merge]"
        },
        projectName, repositoryName);
```

In addition, we can vote on the PR like this:

```
var pr = await client.CreatePullRequestReviewerAsync(
            reviewer, projectName, repositoryName, pullRequestId, authorizedIdenity.Id.ToString());
```

> Is there any way to complete the PR (overriding or not existing branch
>   policies) and proceed with the merge operation?

Comment: You can also use the REST API to complete the PR : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#auto-complete

Comment: What about overriding the policies?

Comment: A similar question is answered at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025417/how-to-programmatically-set-a-vsts-pullrequest-to-complete-automatically

Comment: @pijei the version of the tfs is important in this case and this question is way before the other thread. I will check later proposed solution o check if it applies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GitHttpClient has an **UpdatePullRequestAsync** method.

To complete the pull request you need to update the **Status** property of your pull request. and use the **UpdatePullRequestAsync** method to complete your PR.

Please make sure that to set the the CompletionOptions property to specify whether you are merging the commit, delete the source branch etc.

So your code would look like following

```
pr.Status = PullRequestStatus.Completed
pr.CompletionOption = new GitPullRequestCompletionOption() { SquashMerge = true };
client.UpdatePullRequest(pr, repositoryId, pullRequestId);
```

**EDIT:**

The ByPassPolicy is not available for the released version of Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient yet.

However, if you install the pre-release NuGet Package **v15.122.1-preview** of library **Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient**, you will see the option ByPassPolicy as a property in the GitPullrequestCompletionOptions class. You can set it to true to by pass policy.

Comment: I already did that and works perfectly when no policy is violated. Any idea of how to override policies using the client or how to set the autocomplete?

Comment: The ByPassPolicy is not available for the released version of Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient yet. 

However, if you install the pre-release NuGet Package v15.122.1-preview, you will see the option ByPassPolicy as a property in the GitPullrequestCompletionOptions class. You can set it to true to by pass policy.