# How to programmatically set an AzureDevOps PullRequest to complete Automatically?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, azure-devops, pull-request

When creating a pull request as my code below shows, I also would like to set it to complete automatically. Meaning when all the completion conditions on it are met, the pull request completes automatically, so that the author does not have to manually complete it through the vsts interface.

Any suggestions how this can be performed? It seems at the time of pull request creation I do not have any possibility for this. In other words the interface for creating a pull request does not show any options for auto complete.

Here is my sample code:

```
public static void CreatePullRequestAndSetAutoComplete(GitHttpClient gitHttpClient, string repositoryId, GitPullRequest pullRequest, string mergeCommitMessage)
        {
            pullRequest = gitHttpClient.CreatePullRequestAsync(
                pullRequest, 
                repositoryId, 
                cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None).Result;
}
```

Comment: Also for a similar question see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339126/complete-tfs-pull-request-programmatically#comment91234719_47339126

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 2-step process. First you need to create a pull request, and second update it by setting its autocompleter’s identity, and optionally some other parameters as the code below illustrates.

```
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

namespace CreateVstsPullRequestAndSetAutoComplete
{
    public class PullRequestAutoCompleter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a pull request, and then sets it to auto complete. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gitHttpClient">GitHttpClient that is created for accessing vsts repo, and codebase.</param>
        /// <param name="repositoryId">The unique identifier of the repository</param>
        /// <param name="pullRequest">The pull request to be created, and then set autocomplete.</param>
        /// <param name="mergeCommitMessage">Provides text to post, when the pull request is completed and merged.</param>
        public static GitPullRequest CreatePullRequestAndSetAutoComplete(GitHttpClient gitHttpClient, string repositoryId, GitPullRequest pullRequest, string mergeCommitMessage)
        {
            // 1- Create the pull request.
            pullRequest = gitHttpClient.CreatePullRequestAsync(
                pullRequest, 
                repositoryId, 
                cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None).Result;

            //2- Set autocomplete.
            pullRequest = EnableAutoCompleteOnAnExistingPullRequest(gitHttpClient, pullRequest, mergeCommitMessage);

            return pullRequest;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets an existing (meaning created earlier) pullrequest to complete automatically, 
        /// once all of its completion conditions are resolved.
        /// (i.e., a(many) reviewer(s) has(have) approved the pull request, the author has resolved all the commits, and etc)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gitHttpClient">GitHttpClient that is created for accessing vsts repo, and codebase.</param>
        /// <param name="pullRequest">Is an existing pull request, meaning it was created before.</param>
        /// <param name="mergeCommitMessage">Provides text to post, when the pull request is completed and merged.</param>
        /// <returns>An updated pull request, where the update is maninly about setting the autocomplete on it. </returns>
        public static GitPullRequest EnableAutoCompleteOnAnExistingPullRequest(GitHttpClient gitHttpClient, GitPullRequest pullRequest, string mergeCommitMessage)
        {
            var pullRequestWithAutoCompleteEnabled = new GitPullRequest
            {
                AutoCompleteSetBy = new IdentityRef { Id = pullRequest.CreatedBy.Id },
                CompletionOptions = new GitPullRequestCompletionOptions
                {
                    SquashMerge = true,
                    DeleteSourceBranch = true, // false if prefered otherwise
                    MergeCommitMessage = mergeCommitMessage
                }
            };

            GitPullRequest updatedPullrequest = gitHttpClient.UpdatePullRequestAsync(
                pullRequestWithAutoCompleteEnabled, 
                pullRequest.Repository.Id, 
                pullRequest.PullRequestId).Result;

            return updatedPullrequest;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just set the Auto Complete Identity when you first create the pull request? Does this HAVE to be a two step process?

Comment: It wasn't doable at the time as far as I remember. If it can be done today, sure why not!

Comment: Oh yeah I wasn't saying that I know it can be done, I was just wondering if you remembered the details as to why it needed to be a two step process :)

Comment: Useful to see that the update object is a new instance of `GitPullRequest` - dont' just reuse the one returned by `CreatePullRequestAsync`